# Ring whose identity is $42$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am looking to find an example of a ring, in which the identity is $42$.

My initial thoughts are, well would $\mathbb{Z}_{84}$ work?

Comment: Why would 42 be the identity in $\mathbb{Z}_{84}$?  It's a zero divisor.

Comment: I feel stupid for answering this, but also:  it already has 1 as an identity, and it can't have another.

Comment: @Randall: the conclusion is that since $1$ is the identity, any such ring must have the property that $42 = 1$, or equivalently that $41 = 0$. Hence Lord Shark's answer.

Comment: So would $\mathbb{Z}_{81}$ suffice?

Comment: @ChuckNorris That's a ring with $1=82$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  I was referring to $\mathbb{Z}_{84}$ when I said "it."

Comment: Yes, that was a stupid suggestion.. Finally, I think $\mathbb{Z}_{83}$ would work. That way, $42 \cdot 2=1$  which gives us that $42$ is an identity.

Comment: Huh?  If 42 was the identity there you would have $42 \cdot 2 =2$, not $1$.

Comment: @Randall in $\mathbb{Z}_{83}$?

Comment: "if" is an important word.

Comment: "Identity" is ambiguous. You apparently want it to be the multiplicative identity. And technically speaking, 42 is an integer. The elements of $Z_n$ are not integers, they are equivalence classes of integers.

Comment: I would be *very* disappointed if the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything would be "What is the identity of this ring?".

Comment: @Acccumulation: in every ring, the integer $n$ can be understood to mean $n \cdot 1$ where $1$ is the multiplicative identity. E.g. $3 = 1 + 1 + 1$ and so forth.

Comment: @Glorindel Although probably not as bad as the answer being "Sauron".

Comment: Any *set* containing "42" will suffice as the basis for such a ring as long as we choose the operations appropriately.  And we can then construct a homomorphism with a ring that has "1" as its identity (or maybe that's how we (re)defined the operations in the first place), so it's not entirely clear that having "42" for its identity would be a distinguishing characteristic.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan A ring can contain elements which cannot be constructed by repeated addition of $1$. Take for example $GF(4)$. It contains 4 different elements. But you cannot construct them all by adding $1$ since $1+1=0$ and $1+1+1=1$.

Comment: @kasperd: yes, but that has nothing to do with my point.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How about $\Bbb Z/41\Bbb Z$? A field even!

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on this? I am having a hard time understanding... Is this the field $\mathbb{Z}$ such that all multipliers of $41$ are taken out? How does this give us an identity of 42?

Comment: It's the ring of integers modulo $41$; in this ring, $42=1$. As $41$ is prime, it's even a field.

Answer (score 9):

Take any ring $X$, quotient by the ideal generated by $41$.

Answer (score 7):

Define a ring structure on $\mathbb{Z}$ with addition $\oplus$ and multiplication $\odot$ as follows:
$$x\oplus y:=(x-41)+(y-41)+41$$
and
$$x\odot y:=(x-41)(y-41)+41$$
for all $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$.  Then, $(\mathbb{Z},\oplus,\odot)$ has $42$ as the multiplicative identity.

---

If you want $42$ to be the additive identity, then you can do something similar:
$$x \boxplus y:=(x-42)+(y-42)+42$$
and 
$$x\boxdot y:=(x-42)(y-42)+42$$
for all $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$.  Then, $(\mathbb{Z},\boxplus,\boxdot)$ is a ring with $42$ as the additive identity.

Answer (score 0):

How about the ring $R=\{0,42\}\subset\mathbb{Z}$ (subset as sets only, not a subring), where we define $0+x=x+0=x$, $0\cdot x=x\cdot0=0$, $42+42=0$, and $42\cdot42=42$? In other words, this is just $\mathbb{Z}_2$, but using "$42$" as the symbol for $\overline{1}$.

Comment: Then you might as well just look at the trivial ring with one element, 42.

Comment: @Cyclohexanol: Yes, but that was... well, too trivial. :-) On a more serious note, it sounds like the OP wants $42$ to be the multiplicative identity. And I belong to those whose accepted definition of a ring doesn't require an identity, but when a ring has one it must be distinct from zero ($1\neq0$). So from this point of view, the trivial ring doesn't have an identity.